# Can a javascript Web Worker send events to itself?

Tags: javascript, events, web, worker, message-passing

I have a main javascript file, lets call it "main.js".
This file creates a Web Worker "worker.js".
(see code below)

I want to be able to fire an event from the worker to itself.

For now I'm using a workaround by sending a postMessage to main.js, 
which then replies to worker.js. 
The worker can react to this message without any problems.
So essentially the worker reacted to his own postMessage, which is what I want.
I just don't like the fact that main.js is involved in the interaction from the worker to the worker.

Is it even possible to do this?

**code inside main.js**

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var data = e.data;
    switch (data.msgType) {
        case 'workerWantsToContinue':
            worker.postMessage({'msgType':'continueSentFromMain'});
            break;
    }
}, false);

//start the worker
worker.postMessage({'msgType': 'start'});
```

**code inside worker.js**

```
executeStuff = function(){
    //Do some stuff here

    //
    // Here I want to send a message from the worker to itself
    // Something like
    // postMessageToSelf({'msgType': 'continueSentFromWorker'});
    //
    // I can't use CustomEvent inside a Web Worker.
    //

    //For now I have to do it like this
    self.postMessage({'msgType': 'workerWantsToContinue'});
}

continueStuff = function(){
    //Do some stuff here
}

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var data = e.data;
    switch (data.msgType) {
        case 'start':
            executeStuff();
            break;
        case 'continueSentFromMain':
            continueStuff();
            break;
        case 'continueSentFromWorker':
            continueStuff();
            break;
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Why do you need an event? Just call continueStuff() from executeStuff

Comment: @kennebec In this example of course that's the easiest solution. In my live application, I have to simulate blocking IO with the main application during the execute() function call.
The only way to do this is with an event raised from the main application when it's safe for the worker to continue.